# Id allocation of QgsFeature objects

Tags: pyqgis

I noticed a strange behavior when creating a new `QgsFeature` object and adding it to a layer, inside a QGIS plugin. Let me first briefly explain the structure of my plugin: I have a main function that iterates on the features of a layer and calls two subfunctions at each iteration (let call them `subfunction1` and `subfunction2`). Basically, this can be seen as:

```
main function
| for …
| | subfunction1
| | subfunction2
```

In `subfunction1`, I create a new `QgsFeature`:

```
newFeature = QgsFeature() # newFeature.id() gives 0, which is normal
newFeature.setGeometry( … )
newFeature.setAttributes( f1.attributes() )
…
dataProvider.addFeatures( [newFeature] )
```

Now, here's the issue: after adding `newFeature` to the dataProvider, `newFeature.id()` keeps giving 0 in the rest of `subFunction1` *and* in `subFunction2`. However, in the next iteration, `newFeature.id()` gives a correct, incremented id in all subfunctions.

Note that if I choose a specific id for `newFeature` (e.g. if I write `newFeature = QgsFeature( 99 )` instead of `newFeature = QgsFeature()`), the problem remains the same. The specified id is overwritten by an automatic id, in the next iteration only. Everything else (geometry, attributes) is fine.

So my question is: when is `newFeature`'s id supposed to be set by the `QgsFeature` class (or anything else)? Clearly, it is not immediate but has to wait some trigger. I googled the issue and tried to browse the C++ source, but it didn't help me much.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I will make an educated guess. Since QGIS relies on GDAL for a lot of its data feature stuff, it might be one of the [Python Gotchas](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas), especially about [Destroy()](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#CertainobjectscontainaDestroymethodbutyoushouldneveruseit) and [saving / closing data sets](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#Savingandclosingdatasetsdatasources), so the id gets written, after the dataset has been saved somewhere / somehow

Answer (score 6):

The addFeatures() function returns a boolean (for success/failure) along with a list of features. You can capture these in variables:

```
(result, newFeatures) = vectorLayer.dataProvider.addFeatures([newFeature])
```

Then you can iterate through newFeatures and call the id() for each QgsFeature. If only one feature was added, you can use: `newFeatures[0].id()`

I found this solution [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#add-features). 
I hope it helps!

Comment: @ArMoraer shouldn't this be an accepted answer?