# How to get the feature id of features added to dataProviders?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

My question is somehow related to the problem of [finding the id of the last added feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102376/how-to-find-the-id-of-the-last-added-feature-using-pyqgis): I am looking for a way to supply the feature id and another attribute of each added feature through a signal. The user can change many layers, but only in case of changing a special layer this signal should be emitted/evaluated.

The solution to the question mentioned above is to connect to the `featureAdded` signal of the layer being edited.

Instead of editing layers I am going to add features to the `dataProvider`. In this case the signal is not emitted through the layer.

I see three ideas to prove:

1. Adding an appropriate signal to dataProvider objects (my preferred solution)
2. Changing layers `featureAdded` signal to include feature id and the other attribute (second best solution), and fire it manually.
3. Define an application specific signal and emit this whenever a feature is added to any provider (the easiest way, but filtering signals by this special layer is required)

In all cases one question is: how can I get the feature id of the feature being added to a dataProvider? According to the first and second idea: is it possible to extend the contents of a signal, or to bind one more signal to mapLayer/dataProvider objects?

Comment: Do you still need a solution for this question?

Comment: Yes. My workaround is based on the assumption, that feature ids are incremented by 1. For the use case in mind this holds, but nevertheless a general solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not absolutely necessary for your code to catch a signal...

You can use the `vectorLayer.dataProvider.addFeatures()` method to assign the new feature(s) to a variable. Once caught in the variable, iterate through them and call the `id()` function.

See my [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/215643/85229) to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the "python Init Function" of the layer ?
From the example in the tooltip:

```
def my_form_open(dialog,layer,feature):
     geom = feture.geometry()
     id = feature.id()
```

Comment: When I create a `QgsFeature()` and add it to the `dataprovider()` with `addFeatures()` its feature id is equal to 0. It gets its *id* after being added. Once added to layer or dataProvider it is another feature. In this case this feature has to be queried after being added to determine what the *id* is. I want to push this information to other modules, in order to let them react to the change.